# Data loss is happening due to auto growth of the MSSQL Database

Tags: sql-server, auto-growth

I have a database that is 101 GB in size (as of now) and continuing to increase.
How to stop the data loss that is happening due to the unavailability of the SQL server during the auto-growth event?
I tried with 4 GB then 2 GB and now 500 MB, still I'm unsure it will work.

Comment: Are you actually getting data loss? Databases are built to 100% save your data or throw an error and tell you.

Answer (score 1):

The auto growth is a mechanism to protect your database from stopping unexpectedly when there's no room left for new data, but you don't have to wait for it to happen.
You can grow your database manually during your maintenance window to the proper size you believe it should be to last, let's say, the next quarter without having to rely on the auto growth.

If you see the [Considerations for AUTOGROW](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/sql/admin/considerations-autogrow-autoshrink#considerations-for-autogrow), you'll find out that behavior is expected:

> If the growth increment is large or there is some other factor that
> causes it to take a long time, the query in which you open the
> transaction might fail because of a timeout error.

The [Best Practices for Autogrow and Autoshrink](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/sql/admin/considerations-autogrow-autoshrink#best-practices-for-autogrow-and-autoshrink) doc says:

> - For a managed production system, you must consider autogrow to be    merely a contingency for unexpected growth. Do not manage your data
>   and log growth on a day-to-day basis with autogrow.
> - You can use alerts or monitoring programs to monitor file sizes and    grow files proactively. This helps you avoid fragmentation and
>   permits you to shift these maintenance activities to non-peak hours.